# Which Wi-Fi6 features are mandatory?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Are **all** [listed features of Wi-Fi 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_6) **mandatory**, i.e. do all Wi-Fi6 devices support **all features**?

- OFDMA
- Multi-user MIMO (MU-MIMO)
- Trigger-based Random Access
- Spatial frequency reuse
- Two NAVs
- Target Wake Time (TWT)
- Dynamic Fragmentation
- Guard interval duration: 0.8 µs, 1.6 µs or 3.2 µs
- Symbol duration: 12.8 µs
- Frequency bands: 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz

I know

- a lot of devices can use only use max 80 Mhz channels and not 160 MHz
- a router that only supports the 2.4 Ghz band

If a hardware manufactor does not list some Wi-Fi 6 features explicitly, are the not supported?

Comment: Channels are allowed or banned based on the regional regulations, firmware associated with that region, locks down which channels can be used.

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to get a copy of the IEEE 802.11ax-2021 standard from https://standards.ieee.org/ieee/802.11ax/7180/. Sadly it requires a subscription from a relevant institution so it rather limits the groups who can access it.